# setar option do select como selected com valor vindo de um JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

Boa tarde amigos! Tenho um modal com um formulário de edição da cidade que carrega dados vindos de um JSON. Tudo funciona. O problema agora é que o meu  não seleciona o estado correto. Meu JSON retorna o ID do estado que atribuo a um input hidden. Não sei como fazer para colocar esse valor no . Podem me ajudar ?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <input hidden id="hdIdCidade"/>
                        <input hidden id="hdEstado"/>
                        <select name="estados" id="estados" class="form-control" style="width:400px;">              
                            <?php
                            $select = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM estados ORDER BY nome ASC");
                            $select->execute();
                            $fetchAll = $select->fetchAll();
                            foreach ($fetchAll as $estados) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $estados['id'] . '">' . $estados['nome'] . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>      
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou tentar aqui Gabriel. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem o id do estado dentro do input hidden você pode fazer uma comparação entre o valor dele com o que você tem dentro do select.
com o código abaixo eu peguei os option e armazenei na variável estados, depois peguei o input hidden e atribui um valor, que seria o id que você tem, depois fiz um foreach comparando os valores, quando ele encontrar o option com o mesmo valor do input ele muda o atributo do option para selected.

```
let estados = document.querySelectorAll("select option");
let idEstadoEl = document.querySelector("input#hdEstado");

let json = {"id": 3}
idEstadoEl.value = json.id;

estados.forEach(estado => {

            if(estado.value == idEstadoEl.value){
                estado.selected = true;
            }

});
```

Comment: Deu certinho Gabriel! Valeu demais irmão. Deus te abençoe!